# When Im trying to install easyocr i get an error

Tags: python, easyocr

As a result I get this error:

```
pip install easyocr
```

ERROR: Cannot install easyocr==1.0, easyocr==1.1, easyocr==1.1.1, easyocr==1.1.10, easyocr==1.1.2, easyocr==1.1.3, easyocr==1.1.4, easyocr==1
.1.5, easyocr==1.1.6, easyocr==1.1.7, easyocr==1.1.8, easyocr==1.1.9, easyocr==1.2, easyocr==1.2.1, easyocr==1.2.2, easyocr==1.2.3, easyocr==
1.2.4, easyocr==1.2.5, easyocr==1.2.5.1, easyocr==1.3, easyocr==1.3.0.1, easyocr==1.3.1, easyocr==1.3.2, easyocr==1.4, easyocr==1.4.1, easyoc
r==1.4.2, easyocr==1.5.0, easyocr==1.6.0, easyocr==1.6.1 and easyocr==1.6.2 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
easyocr 1.6.2 depends on torch
easyocr 1.6.1 depends on torch
easyocr 1.6.0 depends on torch
easyocr 1.5.0 depends on torch
easyocr 1.4.2 depends on torch
easyocr 1.4.1 depends on torch
easyocr 1.4 depends on torch
easyocr 1.3.2 depends on torch
easyocr 1.3.1 depends on torch
easyocr 1.3.0.1 depends on torch
easyocr 1.3 depends on torch
easyocr 1.2.5.1 depends on torch
easyocr 1.2.5 depends on torch
easyocr 1.2.4 depends on torch
easyocr 1.2.3 depends on torch
easyocr 1.2.2 depends on torch
easyocr 1.2.1 depends on torch
easyocr 1.2 depends on torch
easyocr 1.1.10 depends on torch
easyocr 1.1.9 depends on torch
easyocr 1.1.8 depends on torch
easyocr 1.1.7 depends on torch
easyocr 1.1.6 depends on torch
easyocr 1.1.5 depends on torch
easyocr 1.1.4 depends on torch
easyocr 1.1.3 depends on torch
easyocr 1.1.2 depends on torch
easyocr 1.1.1 depends on torch
easyocr 1.1 depends on torch
easyocr 1.0 depends on torch

To fix this you could try to:

1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts

I tried to follow the example as indicated in the instructions, but this caused additional errors

```
python -m pip install "pytest < 4.6" pytest-cov==2.12.1
```

ERROR: Cannot install pytest-cov==2.12.1 and pytest<4.6 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
The user requested pytest<4.6
pytest-cov 2.12.1 depends on pytest>=4.6

To fix this you could try to:

1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts

Maybe there is some solution to this error? Thanks

Comment: Are you on Windows?  The installation instructions clearly say you must install `torch` first.  https://pypi.org/project/easyocr/

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you for your response. I tried installing a pytorch but it also caused errors:

pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio

ERROR: 

Could not find a version that meets the torch requirement (from versions: none)
ERROR: No corresponding distribution for torch was found

Answer (score 0):

From the comment, it seems like installing pytorch for you failed. Based on my own experience, I managed to resolve this error by downgrading python. Pytorch does not support 3.10 and older, so I recommend downbgrading to either 3.9 or 3.8

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `pytorch` through `conda`,

`conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio -c pytorch`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade your python version to 3.8, it worked for me. Don't use python 3.9 or higher